# Replacing the first word on each line in Vim

Tags: vim

I have a file that looks like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa bbbb ccccccc
dddd eeeeeeeee ffffff
```

and for each line I would like to replace the first word with "text":

```
text bbbb ccccccc
text eeeeeeee ffffff
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
:%s/^\w\+/text/
```

`\w` is a word character.

Comment: Also: `:%norm cwtext`